# What is the purpose of the Java Constant Pool?

Tags: java, vm-implementation, class-constants

I am currently trying to dig deeper into the specification of the Java Virtual Machine. I have been reading [Inside the JVM book online](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/index.html) and there is one confusing abstraction I can't seem to grasp: Constant Pool. here is the excerpt from the book:

> For each type it loads, a Java virtual machine must store a constant pool. A constant pool is an ordered set of constants used by the type, including literals (string, integer, and floating point constants) and symbolic references to types, fields, and methods. Entries in the constant pool are referenced by index, much like the elements of an array. Because it holds symbolic references to all types, fields, and methods used by a type, the constant pool plays a central role in the dynamic linking of Java programs

I have several questions about the above and CP in general:

1. Is CP located in `.class` file for each type?
2. What does the author mean by "symbolic reference"?
3. What is the Constant Pool's purpose, in simple English?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think understanding how the frame is constructed using a diagram would help.

[image]

The frame is where the operands (operation instructions) reside and that is where the dynamic linking occurs.  It is a shorthand way, so to speak, using the constant pool to keep track of the class and it's members.

Each frame contains a reference to the runtime constant pool. The reference points to the constant pool for the class of the method being executed for that frame. This reference helps to support dynamic linking.

C/C++ code is typically compiled to an object file then multiple object files are linked together to product a usable artifact such as an executable or dll. During the linking phase symbolic references in each object file are replaced with an actual memory address relative to the final executable. In Java this linking phase is done dynamically at runtime.

When a Java file is compiled, all references to variables and methods are stored in the class's constant pool as a symbolic reference. A symbolic reference is a logical reference not a reference that actually points to a physical memory location.

Here is a link to [James Blooms JVM Internals](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html) for more details.

Comment: "When a Java class is compiled..." ? Isn't a .class file already a compiled Java code?

Comment: Yes, a .java file becomes a .class file when compiled.

Comment: All his links are broken.  I'll check back later to see if he reposts it again.

Comment: The link is fixed again.

Comment: "operands (operation instructions) ...". Operands aren't the same as operation instructions as suggested. right?

Comment: Few updates in the diagram:  As of Java 8 HotSpot VM, permanent generation is replaced with Metaspace. Method Area would be represented as Metaspace(HotSpot VM) and run Time Constant pool memory would still be allocated from Method Area as before. The other diff is from Java 7, Intern String Pool would be part of Heap.

Comment: I'm always reminding people to refer to their JAVA version in Q&A as it makes for a better reference.  I didn't do that here.

Answer (score 97):

Constant pool is a part of `.class` file (and its in-memory representation) that contains constants needed to run the code of that class.

These constants include literals specified by the programmer and symbolic references generated by compiler. Symbolic references are basically names of classes, methods and fields referenced from the code. These references are used by the JVM to link your code to other classes it depends on.

For example, the following code

```
System.out.println("Hello, world!");
```

produces the following bytecode (`javap` output)

```
0:   getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;              
3:   ldc     #3; //String Hello, world!                                                  
5:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

`#n` here are references to the constant pool. `#2` is a symbolic reference to `System.out` field, `#3` is a `Hello, world!` string and `#4` is a symbolic reference to `PrintStream.println(String)` method.

As you can see, symbolic references are not just names - for example, symbolic reference to the method also contains information about its parameters (`Ljava/lang/String;`) and return type (`V` means `void`).

You can inspect constant pool of a class by running `javap -verbose` for that class.

Comment: @axtavt- wow! nice explanation. looks like a little typo near "#3 is a symbolic reference to PrintStream.." should'nt it be #4

Comment: But what does "L" mean in "Ljava/lang/String;" ?

Comment: @JackWM: See [`Class.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

Comment: There is basically just one run-time constant pool created by JVM right? Or is there a separate constant pool for every .class files?

Comment: Also, is string intern pool a part of run-time constant pool?

Comment: There is a constant pool inside every class file. It is created by the compiler. The JVM resolves the references of the CP during runtime. The string intern pool is an area inside the VM.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is the second time I see this answer.

Comment: I think the author of this answer is talking about `cp_info        constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];` in `ClassFile {..}`

Answer (score 9):

> What is the Constant Pool's purpose, in simple English?

The CP is a memory area very unique constant values are stored to reduce redundancy:

```
System.err.println("Hello");
System.out.println("Hello");
```

In the CP there is only one String object "Hello" and the compiler substitutes in both lines to the same reference. Your .class file only contains one Hello string. (The same for other types).

> Is CP located in .Class file for each type?

Yes, Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Comment: Would you expand a bit more on the symbolic links perhaps? I think these are most important part of CP

Answer (score 2):

Let give Example  First to understand what String constant pool mean

```
   public class StringConstantPool {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String s = "prasad";
            String s2 = "prasad";
     
            System.out.println(s.equals(s2));
            System.out.println(s == s2);
        }
    }
```

the output will be

```
true

true
```

> what happen here step by step

1- The class is loaded when JVM is invoked.

2- JVM will look for all the string literals in the program.

3- First, it finds the ***variable s*** which refers to the  literal *“prasad”* and it will be created in the memory

4- A reference for the literal *“prasad”* will be placed in the string constant pool memory.

5- Then it finds another ***variable s2*** which is referring to the same string literal *“prasad“*.

Now that JVM has already found a string literal *“prasad“*, both the **variables s and s2** wil refer to the same object i.e. *“prasad“*.

[image]

I hope this be helpful

read more
http://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool

Comment: There is not such thing as 'String constant pool'. There is 'Constant pool' that exist in each class file and there is 'String pool' of interned strings that exist for JVM.

Comment: yea , here I meant String pool , Thank you for comment

Answer (score 0):

It might be interpreted as a brower's browsing history，reducing the need to find or build every time