# Compile Time Constant Usage in Switch Case Java

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

The rules of `case` usage say:

1. The case expression must evaluate to a `Compile Time Constant`.
2. case(t) expression must have same type as that of switch(t), where t
       is the type (String).

If i run this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s=new String("abc");
    switch(s)
    {
       case (s):System.out.println("hi");
    }

}
```

It gives Compile-error as: `"case expression must be a constant expression"`
On the other hand if i try it with `final String s="abc";`, it works fine.

As per my knowledge,`String s=new String("abc")`  is a reference to a `String` object located on heap. And `s` itself is a compile-time constant.

**Does it mean that `final String s=new String("abc");`isn't compile time constant?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [new String() vs literal string performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757978/new-string-vs-literal-string-performance)

Comment: Welcome to Java world where `final` on non-primitive doesn't mean constant.

Comment: 's' is a constant, you can't make it point to some other object. Right?

Comment: you call switch on s and then your first case is s?

Comment: @RamonBoza How is my question related to the one you pointed ?Cm'on !

Comment: `new String("abc")` is not a compile time constant.  Until the method begins execution the String doesn't exist.  (And you generally should not switch on a String anyway.)

Comment: (There is a significant difference between "constant" and "final".)

Comment: Yes, i got it now. Thanks :)

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the variable `s`... `case expression must be a constant expression` means that he cannot use `s` as the case variable. In this 'case' he should be testing case "abc"  not the variable s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this,

```
    String s= new String("abc");
    final String lm = "abc";

    switch(s)
    {
       case lm:
           case "abc": //This is more precise as per the comments
           System.out.println("hi");
           break;
    }
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and
>   initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is
>   called a constant variable

**The problem is your code `final String s= new String("abc");` does not initializes a constant variable.**

Comment: `final String s=new String("abc");`. is `s` a constant or not ?

Comment: @AmanArora see the edited answer `final String s=new String("abc");` No it is not a constant

Comment: @dbw or you can use `case "abc" : ...` which is much more precise.

Comment: "String variable initialised with a compile-time constant is constant." Answer lies here. only String literals are considered compile-time constants.

Answer (score 2):

In Java SE 7 and later, you can use a String object in the switch statement's expression.

You can only use constant expressions in the cases and no variables.

creating a String with a constructor isn't considered a constant.

Comment: `s` isn't a constant you mean ?

Comment: `final String s="abc"`; works fine. `s` is a variable again right?

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more . Because as per Java, we can't assign a new object to `s`;

Comment: Check the answer. I wasn't aware of the definition of a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't consider `new String()` to be a constant (even though `String` is immutable).

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final String s = "abc";
    switch (s)
    {
        case (s):
            System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I guess your `switch (s)` is a typo, there wouldn't be much point in that.

Also, if you're using constants in your switch statements like that, it's probably going to be clearer to extract them as a constant field, e.g. `private static final String s = "abc";`. And even clearer if you were to use an enum instead of strings, but I realise that isn't always possible.

Comment: `s` is a constant. Isn't it ?

Comment: Not really. It's just a field or variable. The fact that you've made it final and have an immutable object doesn't make it a constant. You could use reflection to alter the byte array that backs a string for example. This would change the value of the string, thus violating the requirement for case statements to use constants.

Comment: Even if you change the value inside `String`, you can't change the value inside reference `s`.That means you can't make `s` point to something else now. Which makes it a constant. And as you can see i'm using `s` inside my catch and not `new String()`.

Comment: No, s is just a reference to your string object. Which references the byte array within it. So if you altered the value in the byte array, it would cause `s` to change. `final String s` just means that you can't point s to a new object. It doesn't mean that `s` is a copy of the object as it was at that time.

Comment: In reference you don't have a byte array. Byte array stays on Heap ,but you reference stays on stack. Reference just points to your byte array. :)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you can change the value of `variable S` anywhere in the `switch` so this probably can execute all the `cases`. So it gives `"case expression must be a constant expression"` error and in case if variable is `final` then its value cant be changed.

**EDIT**

In `case` you need to have Compile time constants and `final` variables are considered to be Runtime constants. As final variables can be delayed initialized and the compiler cannot determine.

Comment: `s` is final.How can i change?

Comment: If `final String s="abc";` is compile time.Why not `final String s=new String("abc");`?. Both are initialized when declared.

Comment: Object for the String `new String("abc");` will get memory at runtime and then the value is assigned to it so its not a compile time constant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your trying to switch **and** test the case variable `s`. 
 Which, is throwing the error. `"case expression must be a constant expression"`. This has nothing to do with `s` per se... but using `s` as the case variable. Understand?

Here's a sample using the same variable that works properly.

```
private void switchTest() {
    final String s = new String("abc");
    switch (s) {
        case "abc":
            System.out.println("This works fine... woohoo.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Do something default.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

what about an int or other primitive datatype as compile time constant for switch statement?

```
public class MainClass{ 
    public static void main(String[] argv){ 
        final int a = 1;
        final int b; 
        b = 2; 
        int x = 0; 
        switch (x) { 
            case a: // ok 
            case b: // compiler error 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        final int a = 1;
        final int b;
        b = 2;
        int x = 0;
        switch (x) {
          case a:     // ok
          case b:     // compiler error
        }
    }
}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.