# Java string declaration difference

Tags: java, string

In Java 5.0 , what is the difference between the following?

1.

```
String variable = "hey";
```

2.

```
String variable = new String("hey");
```

Comment: One gives you a reference to a String, the other gives you a copy of a string.  What is your doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very commonly asked question on stack overflow, this has been marked as duplicate so this answer can probably serve as a reference to the answers; many of which have quite high upvotes: -

[new String() vs literal string performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757978/new-string-vs-literal-string-performance)

[Difference between string object and string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal)

[What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java)

Anyhow, my 2 cents, when assigning a literal, you create a reference to an interned string whereas if you use, `new String("...")`, you are returning an object reference to a copy of that string.

Have a read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Answer (score 0):

The first one just creates a reference to the object. The second creates a brand new object. The difference will come to your attendtion when you will use the `==` to compare the two objects. 
For example:

```
String variable1 = "hey"; 
String variable = "hey"; 
String variable2 = new String("hey");
```

When Comparing:

```
variable == variable1 //true
variable1 == variable2 //false
```