# Explanation of the constantpool directive in jca file

Tags: javacard

In **.jca** file documentation, it is mentioned that the constantpool section will look like this.

```
.constantPool {
        /*
         * The first six entries declare constant pool entries that
         * are contained in
         * other packages.
         * Note that superMethodRef are always declared internal
         * entry. 
         */
        classRef    0.0;     // 0    package token 0, class token 0
        instanceFieldRef 1.0.2;// 1  package token 1, class token 0,
                              //   instance field token 2
        virtualMethodRef 2.0.2; // 2 package token 2, class token 0,
                    //  instance field token 2
        classRef    0.3;  // 3 package token 0, class token 3
        staticFieldRef  1.0.4;   // 4 package token 1, class token 0,
                    //      field token 4
        staticMethodRef  2.0.5;  // 5 package token 2, class token 0,
                    //      method token 5
        /*
         * The next five entries declare constant pool entries
         * relative to this class.
         */
        classRef    test0;        // 6
        instanceFieldRef    test1/field1;        // 7
        virtualMethodRef    test1/method1()V;        // 8
        superMethodRef  test9/equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z;     // 9
        staticFieldRef    test1/field0;        // 10
        staticMethodRef    test1/method3()V;        // 11
    }
```

But in actual case my **.constantPool** directive looks like the following

```
.constantPool {
        // 0
        staticMethodRef Callmymenu/<init>()V;
        // 1
        classRef Callmymenu;
        // 2
        virtualMethodRef 0.3.1()V;      // javacard/framework/Applet.register()V
        // 3
        staticMethodRef 0.3.0()V;       // javacard/framework/Applet.<init>()V
        // 4
        virtualMethodRef 0.10.1()[B;        // javacard/framework/APDU.getBuffer()[B
        // 5
        staticMethodRef 0.7.1(S)V;      // javacard/framework/ISOException.throwIt(S)V
        // 6
        virtualMethodRef 0.3.3()Z;      // javacard/framework/Applet.selectingApplet()Z
    }
```

Can somebody please explain me that how to analyze my constantPool directive with the documentation standard.

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming you are talking about [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/java_card_assembly_syntax_example.htm))

You should look into the [Java Card Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/JCVMS.pdf) to understand the purpose of the constant pool. The part of this 'documentation' you pasted into the question is just *an example*. Different classes have different constant pools.

AFAIK the main principle of java card constant pool is the same as in desktop java (with some constraints of course) -- thus you might want to look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#The_constant_pool) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10209952/5128464) to get started.

Good luck!