# Is string constant pool part of the method area or the heap area in Java ? does scp consist of objects ? are these garbage collected?

Tags: string, memory-management, jvm, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a big doubt about whether the string constant pool is part of the run-time constants pool created in the method area of the JVM or if they are part of the heap. I have read multiple articles on Google and some say it's part of the heap while some say it's part of the run-time constant pool.
Also, does the SCP consist of string literals in terms of objects? and if yes are they allowed to be garbage collected? Please guide me on the same for the clarity

Comment: Does this help? https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-constant-pool-heap-stack

Comment: I think this is incorrect

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918399/where-does-javas-string-constant-pool-live-the-heap-or-the-stack?rq=2

Comment: It may help to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833367/2711488) first, to clarify the terminology. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70346805/2711488) may also help.

Comment: hello, @Holger I found your answer fascinating but I could not understand it completely. Can we connect by any means so that you could explain me more in simple terms