# How does the Java Virtual Machine deal with constants

Tags: java

So I compiled this code and decompiled it into bytecode:

```
System.out.println("hi");
```

compiles to:

```
getstatic
ldc
invokevirtual
```

From what I can see here, the literal value "hi" isn't explicitly stored in any bytecode format, so does a .class file also contain a hidden representaion of a stack for that program. For example when I compiled that program would the .class file contain that bytecode, and a heap data structure containing the literal value "hi". And more generally, does a .class file contain more than just bytecode (e.g. a representation of the heap, stack and registers). thanks!

Comment: You said `getstatic`, but you forgot to include `indexbyte`s, which will point to the constants table. `javap -p` is your friend here.

Comment: Rest assured: gender doesn't play any role regarding the efficiency of doing your own research vs consuming explanations from others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constants are stored in seperate parts of class files than bytecode, called Constant Pools.
You can find more information about them here: [What is the purpose of the Java Constant Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10209952/1135979)

The class file format is publicly available in [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-4.html)